# Exception calling "InsertBefore" with "2" argument(s): "The reference node is not a child of this node."

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an issue with `InsertBefore` while trying to insert a newly created XML node `INSTANCE` nodes into `MAPPING` nodes.

Here are the things I have noticed:

- if there is only one `MAPPING` node then the script works fine
- if I call `appendChild` duplicates are made in first `MAPPING` node
- I tried to use `ParentNode` but without success

A following error occurs when trying to call `InsertBefore`:

> `Exception calling "InsertBefore" with "2" argument(s): "The reference node is not a child of this node."`

Here is my script:

```
$inputPath = "C:\xml\input_file.xml"

$outputPath = "C:\output\import_files\output_file.xml"

$xmlFile = [xml](Get-Content $inputPath)

$folder = $xmlFile.SelectNodes('/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER')[0]
$mappings = $folder.SelectNodes("//MAPPING")

ForEach ($mapping in $mappings) {
    $mapping_name = $mapping.GetAttribute("NAME")
    $transformations = $mapping.SelectNodes('//TRANSFORMATION')
    $first_connector = $mapping.SelectSingleNode('//CONNECTOR')

    ForEach ($trans in $transformations) {

        $trans_name = $trans.GetAttribute('NAME')

        $instance = $xmlFile.CreateElement('INSTANCE')
        $dummy = $mapping.InsertBefore($instance, $mapping.SelectSingleNode('//CONNECTOR')) # using this line cause a following error: Exception calling "InsertBefore" with "2" argument(s): "The reference node is not a child of this node."
        $dummy = $instance.SetAttribute('NAME', "ff_$trans_name")

    }
}

$xmlFile.Save($outputPath)

Write-Output 'Done!'
```

An XML structure sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE POWERMART SYSTEM "powrmart.dtd"[]>
<POWERMART CREATION_DATE="19.05.2020 23:58:39" REPOSITORY_VERSION="186.95">
  <REPOSITORY NAME="REP_DEV" VERSION="186" CODEPAGE="UTF-8" DATABASETYPE="Oracle">
    <FOLDER NAME="SHARED_FOLDER" GROUP="" OWNER="idwbicc" SHARED="SHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="6bcbde13-cd9d-49e1-b03f-644dd335af59">
      <TARGET BUSINESSNAME="" CONSTRAINT="" DATABASETYPE="Flat File" DESCRIPTION="" NAME="ff_MAPPING_NAME_Structure" OBJECTVERSION="1" TABLEOPTIONS="" VERSIONNUMBER="1">
        <FLATFILE CODEPAGE="UTF-8" CONSECDELIMITERSASONE="NO" DELIMITED="YES" DELIMITERS="," ESCAPE_CHARACTER="" KEEPESCAPECHAR="NO" LINESEQUENTIAL="NO" MULTIDELIMITERSASAND="NO" NULLCHARTYPE="ASCII" NULL_CHARACTER="*" PADBYTES="1" QUOTE_CHARACTER="DOUBLE" REPEATABLE="NO" ROWDELIMITER="0" SKIPROWS="0" STRIPTRAILINGBLANKS="NO" />
        <TARGETFIELD BUSINESSNAME="" DATATYPE="string" DESCRIPTION="" FIELDNUMBER="1" KEYTYPE="NOT A KEY" NAME="SUPERVISORY_ID" NULLABLE="NOTNULL" PICTURETEXT="" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
        <TARGETFIELD BUSINESSNAME="" DATATYPE="string" DESCRIPTION="" FIELDNUMBER="2" KEYTYPE="NOT A KEY" NAME="SUPERVISORY_CODE" NULLABLE="NULL" PICTURETEXT="" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
        <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME="Datetime Format" VALUE="A  19 mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss" />
      </TARGET>
    </FOLDER>
    <FOLDER NAME="FOLDER_NAME" GROUP="" OWNER="idwbicc" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="6bcbde13-cd9d-49e1-b03f-644dd335af59">
      <MAPPING DESCRIPTION="" ISVALID="YES" NAME="m_MAPPING_NAME" OBJECTVERSION="1" VERSIONNUMBER="1">
        <TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sq_sc_TABLE_NAME" OBJECTVERSION="1" REUSABLE="NO" TYPE="Source Qualifier" VERSIONNUMBER="1">
          <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE="string" DEFAULTVALUE="" DESCRIPTION="" NAME="PERNR_ID" PICTURETEXT="" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
          <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE="string" DEFAULTVALUE="" DESCRIPTION="" NAME="SUPERVISORY_ID" PICTURETEXT="" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
          <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME="Sql Query" VALUE="" />
        </TRANSFORMATION>
        <TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION="" NAME="exp_EXP" OBJECTVERSION="1" REUSABLE="NO" TYPE="Expression" VERSIONNUMBER="1">
          <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE="string" DEFAULTVALUE="" DESCRIPTION="" EXPRESSION="SUPERVISORY_ID" EXPRESSIONTYPE="GENERAL" NAME="SUPERVISORY_ID" PICTURETEXT="" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
          <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE="string" DEFAULTVALUE="" DESCRIPTION="" EXPRESSION="SUPERVISORY_CODE" EXPRESSIONTYPE="GENERAL" NAME="SUPERVISORY_CODE" PICTURETEXT="" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
          <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME="Tracing Level" VALUE="Normal" />
        </TRANSFORMATION>
        <INSTANCE DBDNAME="ADM_READ_HR_HUB" DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sc_TABLE_NAME" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="sc_TABLE_NAME" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Source Definition" TYPE="SOURCE" />
        <INSTANCE DBDNAME="ADM_READ_HR_HUB" DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sc_TABLE_NAME_2" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="sc_TABLE_NAME_2" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Source Definition" TYPE="SOURCE" />
        <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sc_ff_MAPPING_NAME_Structure" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="sc_ff_MAPPING_NAME_Structure" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Target Definition" TYPE="TARGET" />
        <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sc_exp_REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS" REUSABLE="YES" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="sc_exp_REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Expression" TYPE="TRANSFORMATION" />
        <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION="" NAME="exp_EXP" REUSABLE="NO" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="exp_EXP" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Expression" TYPE="TRANSFORMATION" />
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD="PERNR_ID" FROMINSTANCE="sc_TABLE_NAME" FROMINSTANCETYPE="Source Definition" TOFIELD="PERNR_ID" TOINSTANCE="sq_sc_TABLE_NAME" TOINSTANCETYPE="Source Qualifier" />
        <ERPINFO />
      </MAPPING>
      <MAPPING DESCRIPTION="" ISVALID="YES" NAME="m_MAPPING_NAME_2" OBJECTVERSION="1" VERSIONNUMBER="1">
        <TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sq_sc_TABLE_NAME" OBJECTVERSION="1" REUSABLE="NO" TYPE="Source Qualifier" VERSIONNUMBER="1">
          <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE="string" DEFAULTVALUE="" DESCRIPTION="" NAME="PERNR_ID" PICTURETEXT="" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
          <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE="string" DEFAULTVALUE="" DESCRIPTION="" NAME="SUPERVISORY_ID" PICTURETEXT="" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
          <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME="Sql Query" VALUE="" />
        </TRANSFORMATION>
        <TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION="" NAME="exp_EXP" OBJECTVERSION="1" REUSABLE="NO" TYPE="Expression" VERSIONNUMBER="1">
          <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE="string" DEFAULTVALUE="" DESCRIPTION="" EXPRESSION="SUPERVISORY_ID" EXPRESSIONTYPE="GENERAL" NAME="SUPERVISORY_ID" PICTURETEXT="" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
          <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE="string" DEFAULTVALUE="" DESCRIPTION="" EXPRESSION="SUPERVISORY_CODE" EXPRESSIONTYPE="GENERAL" NAME="SUPERVISORY_CODE" PICTURETEXT="" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="255" SCALE="0" />
          <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME="Tracing Level" VALUE="Normal" />
        </TRANSFORMATION>
        <INSTANCE DBDNAME="ADM_READ_HR_HUB" DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sc_TABLE_NAME" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="sc_TABLE_NAME" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Source Definition" TYPE="SOURCE" />
        <INSTANCE DBDNAME="ADM_READ_HR_HUB" DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sc_TABLE_NAME_2" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="sc_TABLE_NAME_2" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Source Definition" TYPE="SOURCE" />
        <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sc_ff_MAPPING_NAME_Structure" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="sc_ff_MAPPING_NAME_Structure" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Target Definition" TYPE="TARGET" />
        <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION="" NAME="sc_exp_REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS" REUSABLE="YES" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="sc_exp_REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Expression" TYPE="TRANSFORMATION" />
        <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION="" NAME="exp_EXP" REUSABLE="NO" TRANSFORMATION_NAME="exp_EXP" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE="Expression" TYPE="TRANSFORMATION" />
        <CONNECTOR FROMFIELD="PERNR_ID" FROMINSTANCE="sc_TABLE_NAME" FROMINSTANCETYPE="Source Definition" TOFIELD="PERNR_ID" TOINSTANCE="sq_sc_TABLE_NAME" TOINSTANCETYPE="Source Qualifier" />
        <ERPINFO />
      </MAPPING>
    </FOLDER>
  </REPOSITORY>
</POWERMART>
```

Resources I have searched so far:

- [Add nested XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090045/add-nested-xml-element)
- [Powershell : Add new XML element after a specific current sibling element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251924/powershell-add-new-xml-element-after-a-specific-current-sibling-element)
- [Inserting XML Fragment after last specific node/element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189657/inserting-xml-fragment-after-last-specific-node-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//` means *this-or-any-descendant* node - but when you use `//NODENAME`, without any qualification, `SelectNode()` or `SelectSingleNode` will start search from the root of the document.

On the second iteration over `$mappings`, `$mapping.SelectSingleNode('//CONNECTOR')` returns the `CONNECTOR` node under the *first* `MAPPING` entry.

Qualify the expressions with `.` to only search descendants of the current node:

```bsh
$xmlFile = [xml](Get-Content $inputPath)

$folder = $xmlFile.SelectNodes('/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER')[0]
$mappings = $folder.SelectNodes("//MAPPING")

foreach($mapping in $mappings) {

    $mapping_name = $mapping.GetAttribute("NAME")
    $transformations = $mapping.SelectNodes('.//TRANSFORMATION')
    $first_connector = $mapping.SelectSingleNode('.//CONNECTOR')

    foreach($trans in $transformations) {

        $trans_name = $trans.GetAttribute('NAME')

        $instance = $xmlFile.CreateElement('INSTANCE')
        $dummy = $mapping.InsertBefore($instance, $mapping.SelectSingleNode('.//CONNECTOR')) 
        $dummy = $instance.SetAttribute('NAME', "ff_$trans_name")
    }
}
```

Comment: Gosh! Thank you so much for help. I spent whole day on it!